# Build and Analyze false positive on leak detection?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I have this code:

```
- (CGImageRef)createImageWithContext:(CGContextRef)context
{
    return CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
}

- (void)fooWithContext:(CGContextRef)context
{
    CGImageRef imgRef = [self createImageWithContext:context];
    CGImageRelease(imgRef);
}
```

This is an Objective-C project building in Xcode with ARC enabled.  Build and Analyze reports two errors:  One on the CGBitmapContextCreateImage line identifying a potential leak, and one on the CGImageRelease noting an "Incorrect decrement of the reference count of  an object that is not owned at this point by the caller".

If I combine these two functions into one:

```
- (void)fooWithContext:(CGContextRef)context
{
    CGImageRef imgRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    CGImageRelease(imgRef);
}
```

I get no warnings.

Static code analysis bug?  Or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By the standard Cocoa naming conventions, a method that starts with the word `create` should return a non-owned reference. You're returning a retained object, but you're expected to return a non-retained object. Thus, the when the analyzer looks at `-createImageWithContext:`, it sees that it's *supposed* to return a non-retained object, but is actually returning a retained object. Hence the first warning.

In `-fooWithContext:`, it looks at your code and says "Hey, according to my naming conventions, `createImageWithContext:` should return a non-owning reference. But then they're releasing something they don't own! That's BAD!" Hence the second warning.

You could fix this by changing the name of `-createImageWithContext:` to something that starts with `new`, such as `-newImageWithContext:`. Or you could annotate the method with the [`cf_returns_retained` macro](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/annotations.html#attr_cf_returns_retained) to indicate to the static analyzer that the method is returning an owning reference.

Comment: Ah, I think I see my confusion - the core foundation functions use different rules.  So CG*Create* is equivalent, ownership-rule-wise, to -new*. Thanks.

Comment: This seems bizarre and backwards to me, given the (older?) convention of CG*Create* functions returning owned references. Is there some good reason why Apple chose to make methods beginning with "create" be non-owned references when functions containing "Create" have exactly the opposite semantics? I'm really confused by this.

Comment: *shrug* Perhaps for the same reason that CF functions starting with `alloc` or `init` don't return owning references. They're separate frameworks, separate *languages,* and they have separate rules. That's just how it is.

Answer (score 0):

I'd imagine it's a "false positive", which makes sense really:

The analyser does not know that the returned value in `createImageWithContext:` is necessarily being released (you could be calling `createImageWithContext:` somewhere else where you don't do a `CGImageRelease` afterwards), nor does it know that the `imgRef` in `fooWithContext:` has been retained properly.

My 2 cents :)